# Updating Custom adapter inside async task

Tags: android

I am loading my custom listview using the async task. 
I show a loading diaglog.
Run the `doInBackground` to gather everything needed.
Then `onPostExecute` I do this to show everything in the `ListView`:

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, pix, paths);
lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Which works ok except I would like the ListView to be gradually updated, not updated when the async task has completed.  So there should be no dialog box, the user should just see the ListView get populated row by row.

Here is my `doInBackground`, what do I need to change in order for the ListView to get updated on the fly, and not at the end.

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(DbxFileSystem... params) {

    try {
        DbxFileSystem fileSystem = params[0];


        for (DbxFileInfo fileInfo: fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath)) {
            String filename = fileInfo.path.getName();
            try{
                if(!fileInfo.isFolder)
                {
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    pix.add(image);

                    paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                }
                else
                {
                    //must be a folder if it has no thumb, so add folder icon
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dbfolder);
                    pix.add(image);
                    paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.gc();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
    return true;
}
```

I do need to rebind the adapter to the ListView, by calling this again?

```
lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Or do you bind it once then any updates to the adapter will be shown in the listview?

[EDIT]  Here is the new code which is trying to use `notifyDataSetChange`d (but for some reason there is nothing being displayed in my Custom ListView)

Here is the onCreate, which creates the adapter, sets the initial values (which will be empty arrays) and then binds the adapter to the listview.

```
lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, pix, paths);
        lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In my `doInBackground` of the asynctask, I am calling  publishProgress(1); in the loop.  I am sending a value of '1' but it is not used.

```
publishProgress(1);
```

Finall, I have the onProgressUpdate, which is using the notifyDataSetChanged, but it is not doing anything.  It doesnt update the listview.

```
   @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress) {

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to rebind the adapter. Just notify the view that the data has been changed by calling "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()". Also note that you shouldn't call it or any other UI operation in doInBackground(). You either retrieve everything in doInBackground, return it as a result and then call notifyDataSetChanged in onPostExecute, or you use publishProgress() and call notifyDataSetChanged in onProgressUpdate().

Since you want "ListView to get updated on the fly, and not at the end" use publishProgress() and onProgressUpdate() like this:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(DbxFileSystem... params) {

    try {
        DbxFileSystem fileSystem = params[0];


        for (DbxFileInfo fileInfo: fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath)) {
            String filename = fileInfo.path.getName();
            try{
                if(!fileInfo.isFolder)
                {
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    pix.add(image);

                    paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                    publishProgress(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    //must be a folder if it has no thumb, so add folder icon
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dbfolder);
                    pix.add(image);
                    paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                    publishProgress(1);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.gc();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
      //  loadingDialog.dismiss();

    }
    return true;
}

}
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
       //check log if paths and pix are updated
       //Log.d("paths_size", String.valueOf(paths.size());
       //Log.d("pix_size", String.valueOf(pix.size());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lstView.requestLayout();
       //if notifyDataSetChanged() fails try the ff:
       //lstView.setAdapter(null);
       //lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, pix, paths);
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }
```

Comment: so where do I put this code?  It is currently in the post execute:                      adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, pix, paths);                                      lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: There's no need to call that code again in onPostExecute. You only have to call it once in the onCreate() method and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() like i've done.

Comment: is this line needed as I don't have a 'values':       super.onProgressUpdate(values);

Comment: I don't think this is working as in the onCreate I create the adapter: adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, pix, paths);   BUT in the progress update, should I am not passing in a newer version of the arrays? How do I give the adapter the new arrays to display?

Comment: Or even better is there a way to ADD a row to the adapter?

Comment: Ignore 'values':super.onProgressUpdate(values);. I've updated my answer. The 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged' "gives the adapter the new arrays to display".

Comment: Thanks - I have updated my original post with the code I was using, based on your answer.  Its not updating my Custom ListView.  Perhaps you can work out why.

Comment: Is "paths" the list holding the data? Check if it's being updated by via logcat: Log.d("paths_size", String.valueOf(paths.size()); Call this in onProgressUpdate. If the size changes, we can isolate the adapter as the problem

Comment: paths is an ArrayList of Dropbox file paths, pix is an arraylist of drawable images.  The custom adapter contains a custom listView with an ImageView for the image, and a TextView to display the path.  I have to update both paths and pix.

Comment: Another question - why would the publishProgress(1); go in the 'finally'...as this will only execute after the entire loop from doInBackground has completed?  I want to update the list after every iteration..

Comment: Yes, fixed!. It's now called after every iteration. I've also provided an alternative method if "notifyDataSetChanged()" fails. Check the lines commented out in onProgressUpdate() : Instead of using notifyDataSetChanged() and requestLayout(0, you reconstruct the adapter with the updated list and bind it to the listview. Hope it solves the problem

Comment: Great I'm going to try it right now, but I think I was running into an issue with initialising the adaapter:  adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), pix, paths);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);............................where should this be done because at the start, pix and paths will be empty!

Comment: What issue? Can you be more specific? Place it in onCreate() after initializing listView.

Comment: I'm going to mark you answer as the correct one.  I have realised I have an issue inside of my Custom Adapter.  In the constructor I initialise a boolean array (checkBoxState=new boolean[images.size()];) - but it only gets instantiated to the initial size of the images array.  It won't increase in size every time it is updated and I will get an index out of bounds error.  I need to fix this issue..THANKS for you help!

Answer (score 1):

When you add data to your adapter, you have to call:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

(Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.)

Comment: the notifyDataSetChanged(); is not working, in that nothing is being displayed in my custom list.  Stepping through the code, my adapter IS being updated with new values.  But calling notifyDataSetChanged(); does nothing.   I will update my code in the main post

Answer (score 0):

call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. If you're reloading the list instead of just adding an element, you can call `list.clear(); list.add(newList); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`